# A story about a planet where people have stopped having children because their life spans have been greatly reduced

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a novel about Earth astronauts visiting another planet of humans where they can't see children anywhere. This planet hides advanced military weapons, spaceships and such.

It is later revealed these humans visited an alien planet before that was infected by some kind of contagious disease where creatures' life spans keep on getting shorter every year and these humans' planet has been infected too. That means that the Earth will face the same fate.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.